# Ham Radio Deluxe not importing QSOs from LotW

Tags: lotw, ham-radio-deluxe

I have various computers that I use for ham radio and I use Ham Radio Deluxe as my main ham radio app, especially it is my logbook. I'm trying to use LotW as a way of synchronizing my logbook among computers.

I created 1 entry in one computer, uploaded it to LotW and I can see it there:

[image]

but when I do a LotW import, I get this:

[image]

How do I import that entry into my other computer's HRD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [Ham Radio Deluxe User Guide](https://support.hamradiodeluxe.com/support/solutions/articles/51000052661-setup-configuration-lotw) says: "First of all, it's worth pointing out the following - despite its name, Logbook of the World (LOTW) is not a logging platform. It was never designed to be a logbook. [...] LOTW is not a method for backing up your log. It is designed to convey confirmations electronically using digital certificates. You cannot download your entire logbook from LOTW (only confirmations)."

What you are downloading from LoTW and trying to import is not the logging information for a QSO; it is the information about the positive LoTW confirmation status of a QSO. If that QSO already exists in your HRD log, then HRD will update its status as "confirmed by LoTW"; if it does not exist in your log, HRD finds no match and that's it.